# Error after upgrade from Magento 1.3 to 1.9.24 ( PHP 7 )

Tags: magento-1.9

I have upgraded Magento 1.3 to Magento 1.9 and implemented inchoo php 7 extension in the process ( so running on php 7 )

Everything appears to work on the front end and the back end - except if I try and get grouped products through the API I start getting the following errors - repeatedly.  Ideas?

Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'session_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `log_visitor` (`session_id`, `first_visit_at`, `last_visit_at`, `last_url_id`, `store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) in /html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235

Comment: truncate the log table , Its just log not more than that, please tell me if you still face this issue

Comment: I posted this thing as a answer  , accept my answer if it help you , so anyone who face same issue in future will get benefit

Comment: Sorry - it didn't work.  the error came back.

Comment: upgrade from 1.3 to 1.9? you're insane :)

Answer (score 0):

this table is just for the `log` purposes , if you dont want old logs then truncate this table and try again.

> for a safer side take backup of table.

Hope this will help you

Comment: I thought it was fixed - but unfortunately the exception has come back.